# Alter pagination start index

Tags: 7, hooks, paging

Is it possible to make the pagination system numbering correspond to the page number you are on?

For example, instead of having /media-releases (page 1), /media-releases?page=0 (page 1), and /media-releases?page=1 (page 2) having /media-releases (page 1), /media-releases?page=1 (page 1), and /media-releases?page=2 (page 2).

This seems like a small change, but I believe an important one for usability.

Comment: I answered [a similar question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53736/how-to-configure-pager-numbers-match-uri-string-in-drupal-7/53741#53741). Although no real solution it might give some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by implementing [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7), and [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7).

With the first hook, you alter the links that are being output from Drupal; you would increase the value of `$options['query']['page']`.
With the second hook, you alter the links being received from Drupal; you should find the `'?page='` string in the URL, and decrease the number after that string.

Keep in mind that `$_GET['page']` can be a string like `'1,2,4,5,6'` if the page has more than one pager. See the code of [pager_find_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_find_page/7).

Also, `hook_url_outbound_alter()` receive the query parameters in `$options`, while `hook_url_inbound_alter()` receives just a string for the URL, which also contains the query part.